# How to rescale list to interval $(0,1)$

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

Imagine I have an arbitrary list

```
l = RandomReal[{-5, 10}, 10]
Out[]= {4.17452, 1.75762, 4.16905, -3.63225, 8.34172, 5.39626, -4.2107, 3.50873, -1.52441, -3.7147}
```

which I want to rescale into the $(0,1)$ interval. I could something like

```
(l - Min@l)/(Max@l - Min@l)
Out[]= {0.668017, 0.475472, 0.667581, 0.0460828, 1., 0.765347, 0., 0.614975, 0.214006, 0.0395148}
```

but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it with a Mathematica function. Any ideas?

Comment: Just `Rescale[l]` would do, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MarcoB Didn't know about `Rescale`. Thank you!

Comment: How you want to rescale depends on what you want to do with the results.  If you're just rescaling to reduce loss of numerical precision in regression routines, then getting numbers between 0 and 10 in absolute value usually does it.  However, if you want to estimate the distribution from which the numbers were sampled from, then it really matters.  Using `(alist - (-5))/(10 - (-5))` obviously retains the information to estimate properties of a probability distribution.  But when the min and max are forced to be 0 and 1, respectively, then you have problems.  Then consider `Standardize`.